# Does the dim[rowspace] ALWAYS equal dim[columnspace]?

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor was hinting this was going to be on the exam, but wasn't telling us if this is true.

I do believe in fact it is true though, because both the rowspace and column space are determined by the number of leading 1's in the row-reduced matrix. Therefore, if there is only 1 row with a leading 1, then both the rowspace and columnspace will contain only 1 vector each, thus making each of their dimensions 1.

Is this logic and the original statement correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes it does.  It's called the "rank" of the matrix.  Do you have a textbook?  Look in there.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions

Comment: Yes, my textbook lists rank as "the number of nonzero rows in any row-echelon form of a matrix A". But what does this have to do with the rowspace and columnspace, as they depend on the number of rows with leading 1's, not just nonzero rows

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you are trying to say, but it seems you may be confusing Gaussian elimination and Gauss-Jordan elimination? The rank of a matrix is equal to the number of non-zero rows when it is reduced to a triangular matrix. Not just the rows with leading 1's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, given a matrix $A$, the dimension of the row space of $A$ is equal to the dimension of the column space of $A$.

These are always equal to the ***rank*** of the matrix: which can also be defined as the number of nonzero rows of $A$ when $A$ is in row-echelon form.

See the equivalent definitions for the [***rank***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Main_definitions) of a matrix.

Comment: Thanks! that was just what I was looking for. Also, in other words the rank = dim[rowspace] = dim[columnspace] then?

Comment: Yes, indeed, Johnathon!

Comment: Nice discourse! +1